# SQL Create weak entity set with ternary relationship

Tags: sql

Consider the following two entity sets

```sql
Employee(ID, name, address)
Dependent(pname, age)
```

here, `Employee` is a strong entity set and `ID` is its primary key. `Dependent` is weak entity set and `pname` is its partial key. The entity sets are related via a weak relation policy(amount).

How should i handle the relation Policy? Do I need a separate table to store the relation and the amount attribute or can I include it in `Dependent` table

Comment: Please, if you can, avoid storing the SSN in a database. If possible, avoid asking people for them as well.

Comment: I don't understand the reason for your suggestion

Comment: where does amount lie? Can you please explain the policy?

Comment: Policy is a weak relation between Employee and Dependent which has an attribue, amount

Answer (score 2):

You mentioned this is a ternary relationship.  Ternary relationships happen when there is a many to many relationship amongst three entities.  In this case,

```
Many Employee --- Many Dependent
Many Employee --- Many Policy     
Many Policy   --- Many Dependent
```

In order to support this in a relational database, you need to break it up into binary relationships.  I'm not sure you truly have a ternary relationship though because you're questioning whether you need a third table.  If the relationship were ternary, you'd be dealing with six tables.  The three main entities and three intersection tables to break up the many to many relationships.

If your relationship is this:

```
One Employee --- Many Dependent
One Employee --- One Policy
One Policy   --- Many Dependent
```

then yes, putting the policy amount in the dependent table rather than create a third table is acceptable depending on your business requirements.

Comment: I would consider your solution and I know how to deal with such relation. But the fact I don't understand here is that the dependent entity is weak. and I think it should be a many to one relation between dependent and employee. and have total participation by dependent with relation policy. that is also simple. but what about the attribute(amount) policy have. I was asking if I can add this atteibute to dependent table. as it looks like a many to one relation.